# Are there databases which work like Amazon SimpleDB which can be run locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I really like the way how Amazon SimpleDB works: Attribute=Value(s) store and SELECT statements. I'm wondering if there are any alternatives out there which work the same way but can be installed locally on my devbox and servers? I've seen one open source project which aims to re-implement the amazon simpledb but claims only to be safe for testing purposes. Are there any stable solutions out there which offer nearly the same features?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095546/amazon-simpledb-for-development-environment-local-installation

Answer (score 2):

Ayende Rahien's RavenDB is extremelu friendly from a developer's point of view: http://ravendb.net/

Answer (score 1):

Check out node-mdb (https://github.com/robtweed/node-mdb).  This is a node.js based clone of SimpleDB.

Caveat: I have not actually used... just a project I'm watching...